# Converting between datetime64 and datetime in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to convert my date column in my spark dataframe from `date` to `np.datetime64` , how can I achieve that?

```
# this snippet convert string to date format

    df1 = df.withColumn("data_date",to_date(col("data_date"),"yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the docs of spark https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference.html, the only types supported by times variables are `TimestampType` and `DateType`. Spark do not know how to handle a `np.datetime64` type (think about what could spark know about numpy?-nothing).

You have already convert your string to a date format that spark know. My advise is, from there you should work with it as `date` which is how spark will understand and do not worry there is a whole amount of built-in functions to deal with this type. Anything you can do with np.datetime64 in numpy you can in spark. Take a look at this post for more detail: https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/dates-times/

Answer (score 1):

why do you want to do this .   spark does not support the   data type datetime64   and the provision of creating a User defined datatype is not available any more .Probably u can create a pandas Df and then do this conversion . Spark wont support it